# How do you turn off (or collapse) the active file menu bar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you hide this menu that appears in the top right of the active file?

I'm not sure what it's called, but I never use it and find it annoying how it covers my open tabs. Some plugins add buttons into this menu which makes the problem worse.

[image]

Solutions I'd like:

1. Just get rid of it completely.
2. Make the 3 dots always appear and all icons/options show up in its drop down.

Also, what is this menu's official name? I couldn't find it in the VS Code docs...

I'm using VS Code v1.43.2 on macOS Mojave v10.14.6

Comment: Disable your `git` integration

Comment: Relevant feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46403

Comment: I'd rather not have to disable all of my plugins/integrations just to condense this menu.

@Gama11 - Yes! That's what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gama11 for finding the open feature request.

---

The solution to this for now is to install the [Customize UI extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui).

And then add this to your settings.json file:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
  ".editor-actions": "display: none !important;",
},
```

[As called out by @jabacchetta in his GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46403#issuecomment-523286973).